# Adding timeout to DatagramSocket - receive()

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, timeout

I need to create a 10 second timeout on this part of the code

> DatagramPacket getack = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
>   socket.receive(getack);

I need it to listed for incoming packets for 10s if it receives a packet before 10s it would skip down to if statement in case it reaches 10s it would jump down to else and resend the packet. Is this possible and how could i do this iam pretty new to this.

```
private static void sendDATA() {
    outgoing = new byte[512]; // Empty array
    try {
        ByteBuffer sDATA = ByteBuffer.allocate(516);
        // 512 - 2 byte opcode, 2 byte block #, 512 data

        DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(outgoing, outgoing.length, InetAddress.getByName(clientip), clientport);
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE));

        int a;
        int block = 1; 

        while((a = fis.read(outgoing,0,512)) != -1)
        {
            data.setLength(a);
            sDATA.put((byte)3);
            sDATA.put((byte)block);
            sDATA.put(outgoing);
            socket.send(data); 

            while(true) {
                DatagramPacket getack = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
                socket.receive(getack);

                if(incoming[0] == 3 && incoming[1] == block) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    socket.send(data);
                }
            }

        }       
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That should work for your example.

```
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
while(true) {
    DatagramPacket getack = new DatagramPacket(incoming, incoming.length);
    try {
        socket.receive(getack);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
       // resend
       socket.send(data);
       continue;
    }
    // check received data...
}
```

Comment: Hm i looked at that but i was wondering if that will work like i meant. Will this work in the principle where if something is received before 10s skip to if and if timeout is reached then skip to else ?

Comment: Also do i put this before or after getack = DatagramPacket();

Comment: @kellax I've made an edit to my post. You have to set the timeout before calling receive.

Comment: @Kellax If data is received the timeout exception isn't thrown. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 4):

```
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
socket.receive(getack);
socket.setSoTimeout(0);
```

Comment: @Rizier123 : I don't speak good English (I'm from Polish), so I gave only code. This can be used instead of same the 'socket.receive(getack);'.