# Java server response to a specific time(timeout)

Tags: java

I'm make simple game(with server) in java.
I would like to receive packets from the server to a certain time, but do not know how to solve it.

What is an effective solution?

For example in pseudo:

```
Thread one:
    tryToGetPacketFromServer(){
          GETPACKET...
    }
Thread two:
    timer(){
     if gettin time of thread one > 5 second;
     print errorr and stop thread one..
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for a timeout system? What are you using to receive packets?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm looking for a library that will measure time of method and if it exceeds a limit will this metod canceled.

Comment: @VinceEmigh i am using `DatagramSocket` class

Comment: So yeah, you want the method to block until it reads in a packet. If the method blocks for more than 5 seconds, cancel the method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding timeout to DatagramSocket - receive()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363078/adding-timeout-to-datagramsocket-receive) If you don't understand, just call `setSoTimeout` on the datagram socket receiving the packet